# Create circle packing charts in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I am trying to find a way to add a circle packing chart to a Google Sheet, using the data in a Google Sheet as its data source.

The only possibility I have found is this from DHUMANITIES
http://dhumanities.appspot.com/circle_packing_index.html

But, either it no longer works or I am not configuring the data properly.

Does anyone know how to do this, create circle packing charts in Google Sheets?

Comment: I imagine that d3.js can be used, though I haven't looked closely at the "how" (yet). But if you want to graph something right now, have a look [RawGraphs](https://app.rawgraphs.io/); click [Use it now](https://app.rawgraphs.io/). I just created a circle packing chart using their sample data, but you can also upload your own data. You can download the final chart as svg, png or json.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I had seen that in my searching. It does not do a very good job with data though I do see they are building a new version

Comment: Have you looked at the answer by @Tanaike in [Searchable collapsible tree using D3js in google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63733286/1330560)? I know that it is not "circle packing" but I was able to repeat his solution both with json in "index.html" and as a separate file (which is to say that creating the data from a Google sheet is just a step away). I've tried to adapt Tanaike's approach to Fleur Kelpin's [Zoomable Circle Packing](https://bl.ocks.org/fdlk/076469462d00ba39960f854df9acda56) but no joy as yet. This is an intriguing question; it's got me hooked.

Comment: Minor success: Refer [D3 add zoom to circle pack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31041789/1330560) and the answer and jFiddle by @CyrilCherian. I was able to use Tanike's methodology to create zooming circle packing in a modal screen.

Comment: So cool!!. and this last reference by `@CyrilCherian` looks promising!! The difficulty for me with many of the examples is the challenge of configuring the data is the jsons. This last method look close to something that is usable in a Google sheet

Comment: Is this helpful to you? http://plnkr.co/edit/faZvO6aJLbw8n4r8x2db?p=preview&preview

Comment: Configuring the data is the last thing to worry about. Google Sheets can do almost anything. Regarding json; I I just used what was there. There's nothing to say that we can't write a function that will take the Google data and present it as a variable full of json (or perhaps csv or tsv) depending on your preference.

Comment: Regarding your own data, the plunker has 3 fields. Is this consistent with your data, or do you have a different number of fields?

Comment: the plunker was just something I had come across.  My data is dynamic as it comes from a data-gathering tool called sumApp.  It can have a min of 10 fields up to 30 fields or more depending on the project. Ideally, there would be a way like in the ` RawGraphs` to define what makes up the chart from the fields present in the google sheet

Comment: here is a google sheet with a common example of data `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tH8omIk-oFZy2n1nGCCqCsGJniEIu992xdube7NjDrk/edit?usp=sharing`

Comment: Thanks. Yikes! ;) How many of those fields do you plan to use in the circle pack? BTW, do you want a zoomable or a static circle pack?

Comment: :), I would like to make multiple views where each view is made from maybe 3 or 4 fields.  Zoomable would be fantastic. Wow I can hardly believe you are working on this

Comment: Ultimately I will try to implement turning the modal into a webpage using this `https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#serve_html_as_a_web_app` so I can embed the circle packing charts

Comment: I got this example of a D3 bar chart working `Creating A D3 Chart With Data From Google Sheets` by Ben Collen: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/d3-google-sheets/ I thought maybe it would be helpful if you had not seen it

Comment: I had seen it, but I wasn't able to repeat it. BUT, this is a good example of extracting the data from the sheet.

Comment: here is my google sheet with it working. The only thing I did was add the sheet id on line 10 of the code module: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rEBmHvydSKi0CNvZShfzL8C-XvIqVPAQ6LSQzorjm6M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: here is the web app: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw20cryGJc8diae0LqCwSrr1jG5FlfXJYQsx6ye7y4IYdpvU7P5hjMQ/exec

Comment: Refer [webapp](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw_Zd1jtQekWZYtGBX60b7XMPM4Eav1eMMIiFRam2g7ut2q8PAwp0Hm/exec) based on StackOverflow [D3 graph circle packing graph coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61148292/1330560). This uses JSON supplied within the script. I wonder whether this answers your question. There is a further challenge (that I will try): to put the JSON data into the spreadsheet and then extract it to the service the script - but it will be a low priority for me.